# How to add a custom 404 page and a different Error page (for other errors) in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Basically, how to do the ff. in SvelteKit:

- Add a custom 404 page first.
- Have a different generic Error page that will show a message/description about the error in SvelteKit

Comment: You can also start by copying the default sveltekit error page `node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/assets/components/error.svelte` to `src/layouts/__error.svelte` and then customize it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After reading through the updated [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#error), I found this:

> If an error occurs during `load`, SvelteKit will render a default error
> page. You can customise this error page on a per-route basis by adding an `+error.svelte` file:
>
> ```
> src/routes/blog/[slug]/+error.svelte
>
> <script>
>   import { page } from '$app/stores';
> </script>
>
> <h1>{$page.status}: {$page.error.message}</h1>
> ```
>
> SvelteKit will 'walk up the tree' looking for the closest error
> boundary — if the file above didn't exist it would try
> `src/routes/blog/+error.svelte` and `src/routes/+error.svelte` before
> rendering the default error page.

Of course, this is your own error page component so you may modify it however you want.

## Outdated solution:

**If you have the following in your code, please update it to the updated solution found in the docs (as shown above).**

1. Create an `__error.svelte` file in your **routes** folder.
2. Inside that file, you can do this as shown in the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/layouts#error-pages):

> ```
> <script context="module">
>   export function load({ error, status }) {
>       return {
>           props: {
>               title: `${status}: ${error.message}`
>           }
>       };
>   }
> </script>
>
> <script>
>   export let title;
> </script>
>
> <h1>{title}</h1>
> ```

3. We're not done yet! You can check for the status code and then render different screen components. (You can configure the `props` inside the `load` function, by the way):

> ```
> <script context="module">
>   export function load({ error, status }) {
>       return {
>           props: {
>               message: error.message,
>               status // same as status: status
>           }
>       };
>   }
> </script>
>
> <script>
>   import ErrorScreen from '../components/screens/ErrorScreen.svelte'; // your own Error screen component
>   import NotFoundScreen from '../components/screens/NotFoundScreen.svelte'; // your own 404 screen component
>
>   export let message;
>   export let status;
> </script>
>
> {#if status == 404} <!-- Used '==' instead of '===' to match string/number status code (just to be sure) -->
>   <NotFoundScreen />
> {:else}
>   <ErrorScreen {message} {status} />
> {/if}
> ```

4. You're all set! You can test it out by changing the `#if status == 404` to like `#if status == 500` to see if everything works. (Don't forget to change it back to `404`).

Comment: You need to include status in ErrorScreen also, otherwise:

  Property 'status' is missing in type '{ message: any; }' but required in type '{ message: any; status: any; }'

Comment: Is there a way to print the entire trace?  For example, on which line number/file the error occurs, etc?

Comment: @vphilipnyc yes, that's possible.
"error" (in the load function) has a property named "stack". So when you add it to the "prop" object, you can use it in your template.

Answer (score 6):

**December 2022 solution**

as per docs: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#rest-parameters-404-pages

create: `src/routes/[...path]/+page.js`
containing:

```
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export function load() {
    throw error(404, '/not-found whatever you want');
}
```

also create: `src/routes/[...path]/+error.svelte`
containing (for example):

```
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
</script>

<div>
    <h1>It seems there has been an error, sorry about that.</h1>
    {#if $page?.error}
        <div class="mt-4 p-4 border-y-2">
            {#if $page?.status}
                <p>Page status: {$page?.status}</p>
            {/if}
            {#if $page?.error?.message}
                <p>Error message: {$page?.error?.message}</p>
            {/if}
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>
```

btw, maybe you have some style in layouts, maybe even layout groups
so be sure to put a layout file in the same dir to apply them, e.g.:

```
src/routes/[...path]/+layout.svelte
```